# Enabling JMX for a application in a Kubernetes cluster and connecting it to VisualVM

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, visualvm

I have a Mendix application running as a pod in a Kubernetes cluster, exposed through a LoadBalancer service. Mendix is a Java application, and I want to enable JMX for monitoring and connect it to VisualVM for debugging purposes.

Where should I configure JMX settings? Should I make changes in the StatefulSet file or the Dockerfile for my application?

How can I connect my Mendix application, running in a Kubernetes pod, to VisualVM installed locally on my desktop? What configurations or steps are needed to establish this connection?

I appreciate any guidance or advice on how to set up JMX for my Mendix application in a Kubernetes environment and connect it to VisualVM for monitoring and debugging.

Thank you!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mendix-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mendix-k8s
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 9376
      nodePort: 30012
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mendix-k8s-stateful
  labels:
    app: mendix-k8s
spec:
  serviceName: mendix-app-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mendix-k8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mendix-k8s
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mendix-app
          image: nethaaji/demoapp:53
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mendix-app-secrets
                  key: admin-password
            - name: DATABASE_ENDPOINT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mendix-app-secrets
                  key: db-endpoint
```

this is my sample yaml file for my application. tell me where can i configure?